# groovy script read list of jenkins jobs from file and update its config

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to write a groovy script to read the jenkins jobs as an input from external file and updating each job name and its config.

I am able to list jobs using getAllItems(), but I need to read the list of jobs from a file.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

So basically, are you looking to read content of file using groovy? This will not be difficult. Please refer https://www.baeldung.com/groovy-file-read . This should be useful for you.